# Why does this code make the Tkinter window continuously resize/grow automatically?

Tags: python, tkinter, callback, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

It was supposed to make the image label resize with the window, but the whole window (along with the image) resizes with a mind of its own.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width=500)
canvas.pack()

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def resize_image(event):
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height
    image = copy_of_image.resize((new_width, new_height))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label.configure(image = photo)
    label.image = photo

image = Image.open("*file path to image*")
copy_of_image = image.copy()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = tk.Label(canvas, image=photo)
label.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)
label.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you need to use a canvas? This can be done with just a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a function whenever the widget changes size. In that function, you are resizing an image to be the size of the label. However, there is likely a border or padding around the image, so this causes the label to grow slightly. Because the label grows, it triggers the `<Configure>` event which again resizes the image, which causes the label to change size, which triggers the `<Configure>` event which again resizes the image, which causes the label to change size, ....

The solution is to make sure that the borderwidth and highlightthickness are zero, and/or resize the image to be a couple pixels smaller than the label so that you don't force the label to grow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some testing I think I have found the solution you are looking for.

Instead of placing the label on the canvas we can place the label in a frame and then resize the frame to match the canvas size. At the same time we can resize the image in the label and even if it is slightly larger than the frame it will trigger another resizing until you resize the window directly.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


root = tk.Tk()


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width=500)
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), anchor='nw', window=frame, tags='my_frame')


def resize_image(event):
    canvas.itemconfigure("my_frame", width=event.width, height=event.height)
    image = copy_of_image.resize((event.width, event.height ))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label.configure(image=photo)
    label.image = photo


image = Image.open("*file path to image*")
copy_of_image = image.copy()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = tk.Label(frame, image=photo)
label.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)

root.mainloop()
```

For an OOP solution see below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        image = Image.open('./Images/green.png')
        self.copy_of_image = image.copy()
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame, image=photo)
        self.label.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.label.image = photo

        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), anchor='nw', window=self.frame, tags='my_frame')
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.on_canvas_configure)

    def on_canvas_configure(self, event):
        self.canvas.itemconfigure("my_frame", width=event.width, height=event.height)
        image = self.copy_of_image.resize((event.width, event.height))
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.label.configure(image=photo)
        self.label.image = photo


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```